# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I was working on security layer in my Spring Boot project and faced with the following problem:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

This code returns:

- String "**anonymousUser**" for Anonymous user
- `UserDetails` object for authenticated user

So, I want to configure this code to return `UserDetails` for both cases. How can I do it?

As I guess, I need to implement custom `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

> As I guess, I need to implement custom AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.
>   Am I correct?

There is a simpler approach and that's the [`anonymous()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java#L831) method of the `HttpSecurity` DSL. Just use that block to set your desired [`principal`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AnonymousConfigurer.java#L79):

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // other configuration methods

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        UserDetails anonymousUserDetails = // your custom UserDetails for anonymous case
        http
                // other configurations
                .anonymous()
                    .principal(anonymousUserDetails);
    }
}
```

Using a [**Null Object Pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)-ish approach may be a good idea for that custom implemention for anonymous user.